# Interpret std::vector<char> as std::vector<short>

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have a vector:

```
std::vector <char> c;
c.push_back(0);
c.push_back(1);
c.push_back(0);
c.push_back(1);
```

I want to convert this into `std::vector<short> s` So that elements would:

```
s[0] == 256;
s[1] == 256;
```

Because if you combine the chars `0` and `1` it makes `256` in `short`.

Is there a better way to convert the vectors like this?

Comment: Use `memcpy` perhaps.

Comment: Relying on this implementation-dependent details is often not a good idea, especially for portability.

Comment: Better way than what?

Comment: @herohuyongtao I would _not_ recommend it.

Comment: @JamesKanze The reason?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Because it doesn't necessarily work.  It depends on too many internal issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with implementation-specific behavior, that could be undefined on unusual architectures, then I'd do it like this:

```
short *ptr = reinterpret_cast<short*>(c.data());
std::vector<short> s(ptr, ptr+c.size()/2);
```

If what you want is to treat the array of `char` as a little-endian representation of half as many `short`, regardless of the endian-ness of the implementation, then it's a little more complicated. Something like this:

```
std::vector<short> s;
s.reserve(c.size() / 2);
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < c.size(); idx += 2) {
    s.push_back(c[idx] & 0xff + static_cast<unsigned>(c[idx+1]) << 8);
}
```

Beware that this still involves a conversion from unsigned to signed type, so it's still implementation dependent. You need more bit-twiddling to make it truly portable.

Comment: yeah, something like that but not exactly...

I am not sure you need the &0xff and your <<8 will overflow unless you cast, plus as they are signed, not sure it handles negative numbers well, so I prefer using unsigned to do this, then just cast it back if necessary.

Comment: @CashCow: agreed, I was just working on it. And a caveat added about the conversion back from unsigned.

Comment: And yeah, the sign issue assumes 2's complement, not sure if that is totally portable but works on all systems I know.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution should ideally write a function that creates a short from two chars, and not rely in platform endianness or the size of short on your platform.

Easier to do unsigned where you can simply do something like `ptr[i] + static_cast<unsigned short>( ptr[i+1] ) << 8;`

If you just want to copy the data directly by casting, it is trivial.

```
const short * data = reinterpret_cast< const short * > ( c.data() ); 
std::vector< short > s( data, data + c.size() / 2 );
```

It will "truncate" the last character off your vector if its size is odd. (i.e. if the char vector has an odd number of chars it will ignore the last one)

Note `data` is only a member of vector in C++11. For older version replace with `&c[0]`